# Firebase Firestore "Order by time"

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore, saga

I am trying to implement a firebase database "order by timestamp" sync but not able to work it out.

for Me, it's not saving messages in "any order"

following is my code block for sync  :

```
let time =  {time: moment().format('MM Do YY, h:mm: a')}
const createMessage = (uid, text, displayName) => ({
  uid,
  text,
  displayName,
  time
})

function * syncMessagesSaga () {
    //ordering by uid does not make sense to me
    const channel = yield call(()=>prsf(({rsf})=>
     rsf.firestore.channel('messages')));
    while(true) {
        const snapshot = yield take(channel);
        let messages = [];
        snapshot.forEach(message => {
            messages.push({id: message.id, ...message.data()})  
        });
        yield put(syncMessages(messages))

      }
}
```

The thing is I have to put the following code block

```
.orderBy("time", "asc")
```

but I am not able to figure out where to add

I am thinking maybe it's due to my send code function not saving in order
code block for my send and save :

```
function * sendMessageSaga (action) {
  const rsf= yield call(getRsf);
  const uid = yield select(state => state.login.user.uid)
  const displayName = yield select(state => state.login.user.displayName)

  yield call(rsf.firestore.addDocument, 'messages', createMessage(uid, action.message, displayName))
  yield put(reset('DCTForm'))
  yield put(reset('MessageForm'))
  yield put(changeNewMessage(''))
}
```

Comment: Ordering is pretty well covered in the Firestore Docs [Order and Limit Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). The examples there are almost exactly what you need.

Comment: yes ordering is well defined in Firestore but I am using redux-firenase-saga .. but anyhow I figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some brainstorming, I got a dry fix for my problem:-
I used a function with array sorting functionality:
Code block:-

```
function compareValues(key, order = 'asc') {
      return function (a, b) {
        if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) ||
          !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          return 0;
        }
        const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
          a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
        const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
          b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

        let comparison = 0;
        if (varA > varB) {
          comparison = 1;
        } else if (varA < varB) {
          comparison = -1;
        }
        return (
          (order == 'desc') ?
            (comparison * -1) : comparison
        );
      };
    }
    yield put(syncMessages(messages.sort(compareValues('time'))))
```

let me know the proper fix if you come around with, till then ill use this 
Thanks